# Why does my Groovy AST transform insert null at the end of my method?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I have written an AST transform that creates a setter for a JPA mapped property (it both sets the local field and calls `setOwner` on the other end of the relationship):

```
private static void createSetter(FieldNode field) {
    Parameter parameter = GeneralUtils.param(field.getType(), field.getName());

    BlockStatement body = new BlockStatement();
    body.addStatement(assignS(fieldX(field), varX(parameter)));

    MethodCallExpression setterCall = callX(varX(parameter), "setOwner", varX("this", field.getDeclaringClass()));
    setterCall.setType(ClassHelper.VOID_TYPE);
    body.addStatement(stmt(setterCall));

    MethodNode method = new MethodNode(setterName(field.getName()), ACC_PUBLIC, ClassHelper.VOID_TYPE, new Parameter[] {parameter}, ClassNode.EMPTY_ARRAY, body);
    field.getDeclaringClass().addMethod(method);
}
```

This works, but the generated method has a strange `null` statement at the end as disassembled by JD-GUI (in addition to an odd local variable):

```
public void setMore(Simple_MoreStuff more) {
    Simple_MoreStuff localSimple_MoreStuff = more;
    this.more = localSimple_MoreStuff;
    more.setOwner(this);
    null;
}
```

It doesn't seem to affect the actual correctness, but it's odd, and it seems like a bug. In `MethodCallExpression`, I found this comment but don't know if it relates, since my method is in fact void (I explicitly set it above, and it makes no difference):

```
//TODO: set correct type here
// if setting type and a methodcall is the last expression in a method,
// then the method will return null if the method itself is not void too!
// (in bytecode after call: aconst_null, areturn)
```

Is there a way to keep the generated method from having the spurious `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not looked at JD-GUI, so I cannot tell how capable this tool is in understanding bytecode, that does not come from Java. But in general disassemblers can only somewhat show what Java code in that case might look like, by no means it is supposed to show correct code from a non-Java language. So better do not expect correct Java code if you disassemble Groovy.

In this case I suspect that JD-GUI stumbles over a workaround we have not gotten rid of yet. In several cases we add at the method end dead code, the const_null, areturn you have noticed. We do this because of problems with the verifier if a bytecode label is used at the end of a method. And since the dead code does not influence correctness we are currently using this solution.

Comment: I notice that the boring setters added automatically are the simple `this.x = param` form and nothing else. Why does that code avoid the redundancy?

Comment: Because we managed to avoid that dead code part for some cases. To be clear: this dead code is not really required. It is there to satisfy the verifier mainly and a result of the internal architecture of the bytecode backend not being able to do the rearrangements of bytecode addresses to avoid the need for this. So in some cases the code is written and in other cases not.